# How to animate dropdown in bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to animate a drop-down in bootstrap-vue, but this doesn't seem to be working. What is wrong with my CSS, or is there a different approach? I don't want to use any library for animation instead I want to achieve it through simple CSS.

**SANDBOX LINK** - [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-khayyam-ffgid?file=/src/App.vue)

```
 <template>
  <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button" class="m-md-2">
    <transition-group mode="out-in" type="animation" name="slide">
      <b-dropdown-item key="1">First Action</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item key="2">Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item key="3">Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
    </transition-group>
  </b-dropdown>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style>
.slide-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.slide-enter-active {
  animation: slide-in 0.5s ease-out forwards;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.slide-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  animation: slide-out 0.5s ease-out forwards;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}
</style>
```